# Override Bootstrap 5 fieldset style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Back in previous versions of Bootstrap (and also with vanilla CSS), the following HTML:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Test</legend>
    Welcome!
</fieldset>
```

Outputs a fieldset with a border, where the legend goes over it:

[image: Fieldset with legend over its border]

Nevertheless, when the same HTML is used alongside Bootstrap 5, the output looks like this:

[image: Fieldset in Bootstrap 5]

**How can I override bootstrap CSS, so the fieldset has its border visible again with its legend over it?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any css can be reset to its default by using revert:

```
fieldset, legend {
   all: revert;
}
```

```css
.reset {
    all: revert;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="reset">
    <legend class="reset">Reset legend</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight! It worked and also looks like a clean solution

Comment: This has no effect with Bootstrap 5, probably due to specificity.  Also, Visual Studio 2022 shows an error for it:  CSS105 "revert" is not a valid value for the "all" property

Comment: The example I made works and uses bootstrap 5. If you're having specificity problems then make sure your custom css is added after bootstrap or make it have a higher specificity e.g `body .reset {}`. Both 'all' and 'revert' properties have 95% coverage so is fine to use regardless of what IDEs say.

Answer (score 15):

Had the same issue and the following approach helped in my case. Refer to the following for further details.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32548

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <fieldset class="border rounded-3 p-3">
            <legend class="float-none w-auto px-3" >Test</legend>
            Welcome!
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be overriding `legend` and `fieldset` in CSS like this:

```
fieldset {
    border: solid 1px gray;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
legend {
    float: none;
    width: inherit;
}
```

However I don't think this approach is the cleanest for this approach, is there any recommended way to achieve this?